# TFS doesn't recreated ASP 5 solution DNX wrap folders

Tags: asp.net, tfs, dnx

I have an ASP 5 solution with an Web Api project. I have DNX set up with local dependencies. It creates the wrap folder as I would expect. When another developer gets the latest and builds the solution, it doesn't create the wrap directories as it should. The way we get around it is to remove and add the references back. That will recreate the wrap folders. I could check in the wrap folders but that would mean adding/checking in a new folder every time i want to add a reference. Here is similar post from another site.

http://www.ceus-now.com/mvc-6-can-t-recreate-wrap-folder/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any setting to configure this for now. You can submit an feedback on [Asp.Net - GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues?page=2&q=wrap&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

The alternative way for now would be checking in the "wrap" folder into Source Control or create a "Before Build" task or a pre-build event to call dnu wrap command to create the wrap folder like the link you referred.